# В Linux Mint 18 Sarah не могу установить IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java

из bin запускаю sudo ./idea.sh

И получаю:
JDK Required: 'tools.jar' seems to be not in IDEA classpath.
Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE.

Comment: а JDK установлен?

Comment: openjdk version "1.8.0_121"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-8u121-b13-0ubuntu1.16.04.2-b13)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

Comment: openjdk version "1.8.0_121"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-8u121-b13-0ubuntu1.16.04.2-b13)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

Comment: В переменной JAVA_HOME какой путь прописан?

Comment: Всем спасибо! Вопрос решен. Переустановил JDK.